# checking fields in csv for a number

Tags: c#, string, csv

I'm trying to stop my process hanging when it sees a misentry in a csv file, which is usually  "#N/A", where is should have a double (I know its a string when read in...)

But this doesnt work, why?

```
String ColumnString = (values[Column]);
String NA = "#N/A";
if (ColumnString==NA);
{
     Console.WriteLine(values[Column]);
     Console.WriteLine("non numeric value detected, Skipping line #{0}", LineNumber);
     break;
}
```

Comment: changed to this as using Linq,,,

Comment: how do you post a change to coding? no {code} option in comment,

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What is the type of `values`?

Comment: do you need to know that ColumnString has at list a numeric character?

Comment: the values{[column] should hold a double value for processing, but hardware issues sometimes result in #N/A being entered into csv file, i have to catch this and ignore that line, or file, until i get to end of the .csv dataset, sorry i should have been clearer,,,, when i test this it always catches it, even if it is not #N/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sure that type of ColumnString  is string the you can check it for at least  one numeric character as follow with linq query

```
bool hasnumeric = ColumnString.Any(t => char.IsNumber(t));
if(hasnumeric== true)
{
//colomnString has at least one numeric character
}else{
//colomnString doesn't have any numeric characters
}
```

Comment: does this work with String though, my csv file has strings in it.

Comment: yes the linq query above will work on any string
you can fetch whole data from csv file into a string variable then check the variable with this query

Comment: do you want to search whole csv for a special string value?
like this "#N/A"?

Answer (score 0):

```
string ColumnString = (values[Column]);
string NA = "#N/A";
if (string.Compare(ColumnString,NA)==0)
{ 
 Console.WriteLine(values[Column]);
 Console.WriteLine("non numeric value detected, Skipping line #{0}", LineNumber);
 break;
}
```